# Adding login page to Swagger

Tags: c#, .net, swagger

Is that possible to add a Login modal to swagger page?

With this I want to use the Token it returns so I can use in all Swagger API calls, inserting directly to Authorization.

I know that there is a configuration we can use at AddSweggerGen -

```
c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new ApiKeyScheme
                {
                    Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. Example: \"Authorization: Bearer {token}\"",
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    In = "header",
                    Type = "apiKey"                  

                });
```

I just wanna user do not have to insert a token manually.

Is there a way to provide a Login page or something like that???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not do that.

I had to use Basic auth. and then create a middleware to treat it and generate a Token.